# Regex Match 2 digits or characters side by side

Tags: c#, regex

I have been trying to get this to work all morning and I cannot just seem to get it correct.

Let's say I have a string that may look like `AA87AK8766KKTA%$`.

And I was trying to get AA 66 KK out of it. I cannot figure this out as I have tried

```
[A-Z0-9]{2}
([A-Z0-9]{2})-([A-Z0-9]{2})
```

among others that I've found and I cannot get this correct.

Comment: Try a capturing group with a backreference `([A-Z0-9])\1` See https://regex101.com/r/3V6JaI/1

Comment: thank you that does it can you please explain why?

Comment: The first capturing group matches either A-Z or 0-9. After that match you refer to what has been captured in group 1 using `\1` This page might be helpful https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This will help you:***

```
([A-Z0-9])\1
```

***now the explaination:***

I use `[A-Z0-9]` inside a capture group, therefore the braces.
`\1` machtes exactly the same string as the capture group number `1` matched before, so in your example `([A-Z0-9])`. See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sqY9rp/1) for a full explanation.

i.e. if we add braces around the query `([A-Z0-9])` will get capture group number `2` so we you have to modify the `\1` as well: `(([A-Z0-9])\2)`

If you want to match the same char three times you can modify the regex like this `([A-Z0-9])\1{2}`

***Your mistake***

In `[A-Z0-9]{2}` the `{2}` means match the previous pattern twice, but the pattern matches all characters and numbers so it results i.e. this first match: `AA`, but the second match is `87`

Answer (score 2):

I like **@Thefourthbird** answer. Thanks man

I just want to explain it in another way.

First at all, you seem to be looking for duplicate pair of characters and want to avoid special characters from:

```
AA87AK8766KKTA%$
```

So. taking that in mind:

`[A-Z0-9]` will look character by character that match with a-z letters or 0-9 numbers.

This means that all but special characters will match.

```
A A 8 7 A K 8 7 6 6 K K T A
```

Each letter will be now a capturing group

Now, adding parenthesis and a `\1` at the end of this regex like this:

```
([A-Z0-9])\1
```

It will to duplicate each first capturing group, one by one, and will to reapply the regex to the whole string.

In that way, this will look for duplicates side by side.

```
AA AA 88 77 AA KK 88 77 66 66 KK KK TT AA
```

If you are looking for triplicates side by side, then you just have to add another `\1`

`([A-Z0-9])\1\1`

```
AAA AAA 888 777 AAA KKK 888 777 666 666 KKK KKK TTT AAA
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/FOomHj/1

**Subject:** Using Backreferences To Match The Same Text Again

https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html